# How to call Angular 2.0 beta function from html which is bound from jQuery

Tags: angular

I am binding extra html into fullcalendar latest version 2.5.0 and want a click event that will call a function.

```html
import {Component, ElementRef, Inject, OnInit} from 'angular2/core'; import {ROUTER_DIRECTIVES} from 'angular2/router'

import 'jquery' import 'fullcalendar';

declare var jQuery: any;

@Component({
selector: 'ite-calendar',
templateUrl: 'views/calendar.html',
directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]

})

export class CalendarComponent implements OnInit {
elementRef: ElementRef;

constructor( @Inject(ElementRef) elementRef: ElementRef) {
    this.elementRef = elementRef;
}
  ngOnInit() {
    var el: HTMLElement = this.elementRef.nativeElement;
   var calendar = jQuery(el).find(".calendar");
    calendar.fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
        defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
        defaultDate: '2015-12-06',
        editable: true,
        eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
        events: this.getAllEvents(),
        eventAfterRender: function (event, element, view) {
            var content = event.description;
            if (content != undefined) {
                var html = "";
                html += `<div class="contentDiv">` + content + `</div>`;
                element.append(html);
                el.querySelector(".contentDiv").addEventListener("click", function () {
                        console.log("Clicked");
                });

            }
        }
    });
}

getAllEvents() {
    return [
        {
            title: 'Half Day Event',
            start: '2015-12-06T10:30:00',
            allDay: false,
            className: 'defaultCal',
            editable: false,
            description: 'This is a cool event'
        },
        {
            title: 'All Day Event',
            start: '2015-12-02',
            allDay: true
        },
        {
            title: 'Long Event',
            start: '2015-12-07',
            end: '2015-12-10'
        },
        {
            id: 999,
            title: 'Repeating Event',
            start: '2015-12-09T16:00:00'
        },
        {
            id: 999,
            title: 'Repeating Event',
            start: '2015-12-16T16:00:00'
        },
        {
            title: 'Conference',
            start: '2015-12-10',
            end: '2015-12-12'
        },
        {
            title: 'Meeting',
            start: '2015-12-12T10:30:00',
            end: '2015-12-12T12:30:00'
        },
        {
            title: 'Lunch',
            start: '2015-12-12T12:00:00'
        },
        {
            title: 'Meeting',
            start: '2015-12-12T14:30:00'
        },
        {
            title: 'Happy Hour',
            start: '2015-12-12T17:30:00'
        },
        {
            title: 'Dinner',
            start: '2015-12-12T20:00:00'
        },
        {
            title: 'Birthday Party',
            start: '2015-12-13T07:00:00'
        },
        {
            title: 'Click for Google',
            url: 'http://google.com/',
            start: '2015-12-28'
        }
    ]
} }
```

Comment: Can you please remove all those > at the beginning of each code line. I guess you need to use `NgZone.run()`

Comment: thanks working now 
"<div class="fc-bg"></div>" this element is higher than "<div class="contentDiv"><button class="clickMe">Click Me</button></div> "

Comment: Please edit your question and improve code formatting and also please add an answer where you show how you solved the problem. I don't know JS, TS, jQuery well enough (I use Angular2 only from Dart).

Comment: Created a plunker
http://plnkr.co/edit/QaW8Ez6Cv63odVyR5Ywn?p=preview

Comment: Are you not yet allowed to create an answer? Again, please edit your question and improve the code formatting.

Comment: but not able to call Angular function callWhenButtonClick().
please check plunker and let me know

Comment: How to allow for an answer

Comment: Looks like you need 1 reputation.

Comment: Have you considered PrimeNG Schedule that uses FullCalendar. http://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/schedule

Answer (score 0):

```
Below is the plunker with correct answer provided by 

https://github.com/robwormald


http://plnkr.co/edit/WRXpdkAcobUKhdNpEmuo?p=preview
```